# C++: Passing pointer to a class while constructing it

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

If I have a `class Foo` and a method with the prototype `void bar(Foo* foo)`. Is it okay to do: `bar(&Foo());`?

I know it compiles and works, but since I'm relatively new to C++, I was wondering whether the instance created will be correctly destructed after usage, or if I have to worry about anything else when doing that.

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? You can't take the address of a temporary.

Comment: What would be the point of doing this?

Comment: Agreed mate.. there's no point to this call. Assume that it worked. the Foo object wouldn't be accessible to anything outside of the bar function.

Comment: Curios.. what language are you coming from that something like this would be of use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not even valid C++. Some compilers may be silly and accept it, but they shouldn't do it. You cannot take the address of a temporary.

This restriction is given in section §5.3.1 of the C++ standard:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its
>   operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*.

Temporaries are prvalues, so they cannot have their address taken.

Now, assuming your compiler accepts this, the pointer will be valid while the function call runs, *but only* while it runs. Once it returns the temporary is destroyed, so any pointers to it that still exist (like, if the function stored it) are invalid.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this, I'm using MSVC++2010 and in that it compiles and works fine - but I will not take that as a reference then!

Comment: @nijansen this is an important lesson to learn early, that just because a compiler allows it does not mean it is valid C++.

Comment: I've deleted my answer due to noncompetence, but this http://ideone.com/SHCIc compiles only with a warning. Are you sure this is not valid C++?

Comment: What @SethCarnegie said, plus turning up compiler warnings can save you a lot of grief and help you adhere to the standard.

Comment: @Beginner Yes, I am. Sadly, GCC has extensions too :( It's a good idea to always compile with `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++11` (thus disabling extensions) and warnings enabled (I use the `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` flags).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes what is the difference between `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11`?

Comment: This `g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wall foo.cpp` still gives only a warning.

Comment: Seth: None. But `-std=c++11` is only available on more recent builds (not sure when it started.) @Beginner: well, that's sad :( But if you want proof I can provide a standard quote.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, please, if it's not difficult. I think it should be added to the answer too, since compilers are so silly to accept it.

Comment: Not that I'd ever do the above.. But couldn't this be used as a cheep polymorphic function call?  Use a this to sub in a local for example.  Ugly.. but it would work.

Comment: It's weird that compilers seem to be rather tolerant of this really bad idea. I wanted to add, however, that it is nice to see that in gcc 4.6 this has been changed from a warning to an error:
4.5: `badAddress.cpp:9:14: warning: taking address of temporary`

4.6: `badAddress.cpp:9:14: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid, in the general case. `Foo()` is a temporary which will be dead as soon as `bar` returns. MSVC will incorrectly accept it, as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the code will compile? With gcc you'll get `error: taking address of temporary`.

The reason why you *shouldn't* (and with some compilers *can't*) take the address of a temporary is because it'll go out of scope (therefore being destroyed/deconstructed) and the address passed to `bar` won't be that of a real `Foo` object that you have permission to access.

Comment: Yes, it compiles using MSVC++2010

Comment: @nijansen: really? Does it give any sort of warning?

Comment: I have used this in the default Debug mode of the MSVC compiler, and it works and does not throw any warnings. I thought this was strange myself which is why I was asking whether it's conform.

Comment: good point.. even if he manages to assign a local member variable to the pointer that was passed, when bar is over the object there wouldn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using native C++, then you can disable the language extensions in MSVC2010.

Project->Properties->C/C++->Language->Disable Language Extensions.

```
struct Foo
{
};

void bar(Foo* foo)
{
}


int main()
{
    bar(&Foo());
}
```

**Output:**

1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Test.cpp
1>Test.cpp(16): error C2102: '&' requires l-value
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I can see only one reason for this.. If you had to decide between using a pointer or a local, then this would be an (ugly) approach. 
If you want a local, then your call would work.. If however you planned on using a passed in one, then that too would work..

A more logical approach would be to have a function override with no parameters.

```
void bar(){ Foo f;  bar(&f);} 
void bar(Foo * ifoo){...}
```

Personally I'd never do what you did.. but here's why it should compile and why it shouldn't.

Comment: strictly speaking his method would be faster, because it would avoid a function push/pop

Comment: I'm pretty sure most compilers will produce the same code for both cases.

Comment: That I suppose depends on how you've got your system optimized. 

But if the compiler would produce the same code for both, why then is the sample he gave bad. (other than that it's very ugly)

Comment: The sample is bad because it's not portable. It depends on a compiler extension.

Comment: Ah.. Martinho.. but as stipulated in the comment.. the compile would produce the same code.. 
    if(compiledCodeA == compiledCodeB){ AskWhyBad();} else {duh();}

Comment: PS  Martinho.. it's bad for a heap more reasons than that.. it's hard to read.. it doesn't convey what it is.. It needlessly passes variables to a function.... the portability issue aside.. it is ugly code.